# Extending a class that is not defined during compile time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop

I'm working on a bot in actionscript for a flash game, with some success. My actionscript basically loads the game, finds the functions it needs and calls it to do stuff. For example, ExternalLoadedGame.Game.Action.MoveNorth() to take a step up.

However, some functions are defined as protected, and I can only get access if I can extend that class, but when I try to do that, my compiler tells me that the class is not Compile time consistent and it doesn't work. And if I copy the definition, the game functions don't accept my version of the class, even though it's literally they share literally the same class definition.

I need to specifically override some of the class functions that are called by the game, without access to modify the game files.

Is there any way to extend, make public, or anything similar without modifying the game's SWF file beforehand?

Comment: I don't think actionscript has the same freedom as javascript, so the answer is probably no. Rarely does any language allow you to have dynamic classes (type checking stuff).

Comment: Even if you do extend these classes, it will not give you runtime access to protected functions of instances created by the game code.

Comment: if you need access to those function then they shouldn't be protected in the first place. You of course can't extend a class at runtime or access protected functions of any class.